# Avaya Telephone Address Names

Tags: tapi, avaya

I am using Interop.TAPI3Lib.dll to connect to my companies Avaya office telephones the AddressNames returned from the TAPI library are of the format "IP Office Phone: 805". Could someone please tell me how these address names are configured as I would prefer for the extension only be used as the AddressName.